# change format of C++/CLI stopwatch from System::Diagnostics windows form CLR

Tags: c++-cli, clr, windows-forms-designer, stopwatch

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) { 

this->label3->Text = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();}
```

I need help for changing the format of my stopWatch, how can i put a format like "HH:mm:ss" please ?
because doing this just show the default format that shows too much numbers

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-timespan-tostring(system-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Stopwatch.Elapsed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed?view=net-6.0) is of type [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-6.0).

This type supports various formats when converting to string.
You can see all the info here: [Standard TimeSpan format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings), [Custom TimeSpan format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings).

In your case I think the following custom format string will work:

```
System::String ^ text = stopWatch->Elapsed.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
this->label3->Text = text;
```

Comment: System::String ^ text = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
this->label3->Text = text;

i don't understand why but it doesn't work with an "->", it's only with a "." , thanks a lot, there are a lot to read just for doing that

Comment: @Yissou how did you declare `stopWatch` ? Is it not a `System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch ^` ?

Comment: i simply did: `Stopwatch^ stopWatch = gcnew Stopwatch();` @wohlstad
and yes it windows diagnostics

Comment: Objects with `^` allocated with gcnew are usually derefernced with `->`. In my VS2017 environment `stopWatch.Elapsed` doesn't compile (only `stopWatch->Elapsed`).

Comment: that is weird because i'm also on VS2017 and for me it's `stopWatch->Elapsed` that doesn't compile ... i was thinking that diagnostics stopwatch is a c# library so it was normal to put "."  ..

Comment: It's a .NET class. .NET is not bound to a specific language (although C# is a very "natural" choice for using with it). When you access a .NET object from C#, you need to use ".". But when you access it from c++/cli the syntax is supposed to be different. Anyway I'm glad you got it to work as you need.